# Does variable value change which is used inside Lock statement c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, arraylist

```
   public Response Delete(Request fRequest)
        {
            Response fResponse = new Response();
            try
            {

                    foreach (Record rec in fRequest.Records)
                    {
                        string personid = rec.PersonId;
                        int recordId = rec.RecordId;

                        EnrollRecord record = (from lst in listEnrolledCandidates
                                            where lst.PersonId == personid && lst.RecordId      == recordId
                                            select lst).FirstOrDefault();
                      lock (lockDelete)
                      {
                        listEnrolledCandidates.Remove(record);

                        int aIndex = record.ArraryIndex;  
                        pvTemplatesArrayList.RemoveAt(aIndex)                       

                      }
                    }

                    return fResponse;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


                return null;
            }

        }
```

In the above source code lock is hold on Remove statement. It means only one thread at a time can execute these three lines of code. Now if a thread (say 'A') is executing these 3 lines and another thread (say 'B') invokes "Delete" method with another Request parameter, Is it possible that thread A gets updated value of EnrollRecord, personid andrecordid while executing operation as Request object  is different ?

Comment: this can have unexpected behavior,why not have the statement to query enrollrecord inside the lock as well.

Comment: I agree, assuming that listEnrolledCandidates is an arraylist (inferred from the tags) then if 2 threads request the removal of the same record and both get to the lock at the same time, the first one removes the record and the item from pvTemplatesArrayList, then the next one doesn't remove the record (because arraylist.remove doesn't do anything if the item isn't in the arraylist) but the pvTemplatesArrayList will have the item at the array index removed. I think there will be many of these types of race conditions.

Comment: Matt, please suggest something to solve such problem.

Comment: please see my recommendation as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the declaration of the lockDelete variable is missing from your question. therefore it is not possible to predict how the behaviour will be. Please update your code to include this info.

Comment: Maarten, how the declaration of lockDelete affect the behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think 'personId' and 'recordId' will have their values changed depending on each threads execution (this assumes that the fRequest parameter is unique to each thread)

However, 'record' could get strange things happening to it. Not changed values, but things like thread A gets its value, then thread B removes the value from the list so it's not actually in there any more.

Any 'global' or shared variable needs to have its access synchronised in a multi-threaded situation.

I'd move the list access inside the lock.

Answer (score 1):

yes , that's seems completely possible so `EnrollRecord record = (from lst in listEnrolledCandidates
                                            where lst.PersonId == personid && lst.RecordId      == recordId
                                            select lst).FirstOrDefault();` must be a part of critical section and protected against multiple threads.

Comment: But "EnrollRecord record" will be treated as a local object in context of Thread A. A will contain its own copy and thread B will contain its own copy. Is it not ?

Comment: listEnrolledCandidates is global not EnrollRecord

Answer (score 0):

- No, thread B will not change thread A's values of `recordid and`personid`
- No, thread B will not change thread A's *reference* to `record`, but thread B could update the *internal state of the `EnrollRecord` object* if they both reference the same `EnrollRecord` object.
- Most importantly, though, your method is possibly not thread safe:

**EDIT:**

I am not allowed to comment, so to add clarity around your question in your other comment:

> But "EnrollRecord record" will be treated as a local object in context of Thread A. A will contain its own copy and thread B will contain its own copy. Is it not

This is probably not the case, and is important to understand. `EnrollRecord`, I assume, is a class. Therefore it is a reference type. Each thread can refer to the same object through `record`, but it's reference variable `record` is not shared between threads. As your code stands each thread will not create a distinct copy of the `EnrollRecord`. Exceptions to this are, for instance, where your linq query is causing a sql query to occur, and your data provider is allowing duplicate copies of an object to be created in memory. I'm assuming this is not the case as you are using a lock to protect your delete, suggesting a common in-memory collection for `listEnrolledCandidates`.

**END EDIT, continue with original answer:**

To make this method thread safe you may need to protect the following line with a lock as well:

```
EnrollRecord record = (from lst in listEnrolledCandidates
                                        where lst.PersonId == personid && lst.RecordId      == recordId
                                        select lst).FirstOrDefault();
```

### Why?

I'll attempt to break your question up into its parts, and answer each of them:

1. Only one thread at a time can execute the 3 lines within the lock
2. Is it possible that thread A gets an updated value of the following while executing operation as Request (`fRequest`) object is different:

   - `EnrollRecord`
   - `personid`
   - `recordid`

So, we'll assume from your statement "as Request (`fRequest`) object is different" that you mean:  The Request (`fRequest`) object is created separately, and so it is not a reference that may be shared between thread A and B.

Putting this together:

> Only one thread at a time executes the 3 lines within the lock block.

I know this wasn't a question, but it is important to clarify this initially, as it helps to understand why `personid` and `recordId` on thread A will not be updated by thread B.

Any number of threads can enter a method, but you need to keep in mind the *scope* of the objects that the method accesses. You can almost picture the method as it is written as being a "blueprint", and when a thread enters a method it creates a physical construct from that blueprint. Each thread has its own physical construct. View the blueprint as the design of a car. You and I may drive the same make, model, year, colour of car, but you don't sit on my lap while I'm driving, and when you change the radio station my radio station doesn't change - we each have our own copy.

In your example:

1. `string personid` is scoped to the method, so its value is specific to the thread calling this method.
2. the same applies to `int recordId`
3. `EnrollRecord record` is also scoped to the method, so the `record` you refer to in thread A isn't updatable by the `record` in thread B.

However, `record` is a *[reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/490f96s2.aspx)*, unlike `int` which is a *[value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)*. This is very important. `record` is a *reference* to an object. It is scoped within a method. Each thread may therefore hold a reference to the same object, or to a different object. If a thread changes it's reference it will not affect another thread, but if they change something within the reference object (see **Other points** below) then both threads will see the change.

If any of these were class fields instead of method variables, then one thread could change the value/reference another thread see's.

### Reference types vs. Value types

**Value Types**: If thread A updates the variable recordId, thread B won't see this. If recordId was declared as a field at the class level (e.g. private int recordId) instead of a variable at the method level, as it is, then this would not be the case - any thread would have the same access to the value and could both read and update it. To understand why this is, you need to look into the difference between stack and heap storage, and at variable scope. 
Take home: a value type, declared and used within a method, is (mostly) not accessible by other threads running the same method.

**Reference Types** 
 - If thread A sets the value `record` to the record with (`PersonId`, `RecordId`) of (1, 1), and then thread B sets it to the record corresponding to (2, 2), then thread A will still refer to (1, 1).
 - If thread A sets the value `record` to the record with (`PersonId`, `RecordId`) of (1, 1), and then thread B sets it to the record corresponding to (1, 1), then thread A will still refer to (1, 1), and so will thread B.

### The lock

So, yes, only one thread at a time can enter the lock region, but you don't need locks to protect locally declared variables. Locks are required to protect shared state, not variables that are local to a thread. If this wasn't the case we couldn't run the following method from multiple threads and get the right answer:

```
public int MinusOne(int value) { 
    int newValue = value - 1; 
    return newValue; 
}
```

## The most important point of your question

The most important part of the question is what you didn't actually ask. The question is:
***Is this method thread-safe***

As I see your code, the answer has to be: ***NO***

I must assume, for the purposes of answering your question, that `listEnrolledCandidates` is a shared reference to a list of type `IEnumerable<EnrollRecord>`. I must also assume that, because you are using locking to delete a record from this list, that it is NOT a thread-safe collection/list/dictionary.

This is crucial:
You are locking so that thread B cannot try and delete a record from `listEnrolledCandidates` while thread A does, but what happens in the following scenarios:

Scenario 1.

- thread A sets the reference to `record` within its scope
- thread B starts enumerating `listEnrolledCandidates` to find a record
- thread A deletes the record
- thread B finishes enumerating

Scenario 2.

- thread A sets the reference to `record` corresponding to the search key (1, 1)
- thread B sets the reference to `record` corresponding to the search key (1, 1)
- thread A now deletes the record
- thread B now deletes the record

In both these scenarios you are likely to eventually encounter problems. If you are using a non-thread safe collection, list, dictionary, you must protect both searches, enumerations, loops as well as adds, deletes, updates etc. For these purposes you can either aggressively use `lock`, or you can use a ReaderWriterLock (or a slim version of the same).

In the second scenario you also want to check again when you enter the delete lock region that the record still exists, in case Remove throws an exception that the `record` is no longer in the collection.

### Other points

Assume you have a property on `EnrollRecord` such as `public string EnrollYear { get; set; }`. Assume also that thread A and thread B both refer to the (`PersonId`, `RecordId`) of (1, 1). 
 - If thread A changes `EnrollYear` on `record` to a new value, then thread B will see this change.
 - If thread A sets `record` to `null`, then thread B will not see record as `null`, it will still see hold its reference to record

In our car example: if you call the radio station that I am listening to (lets say RadioStation is an object with a property CurrentSong) and request a new song, you will change the song that I am listening to. (I think I've taken that analogy as far as I am willing to).

*In this example each thread holds a separate reference to the **same** object*